# Index/Key of type Index that is unique Vs Index/Key of type Unique Key

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on an sql server 2008 r2. And  I have the following :-

1. And Index/Key of type Index that is unique.
2. And an Index/Key of type unique key.

is there any differences between the two . i mean to have a unique key on a column or to have an index that is unique on the same column ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a progressive list of concepts that should help clear things up:

- Logical level:

  - **"Key"** - a column (or combination of columns) that contains unique values for all rows in the table.
  - All keys in the table are logically equivalent, but for practical and historical reasons we choose one of them as **"primary"**, and the rest are **"alternate"**. Primary key is represented by PRIMARY KEY constraint and alternate key is UNIQUE constraint.
  - All keys are unique, so saying "unique key" is redundant.
  - Keys change the meaning of data by restricting what data is considered valid.
- Physical level:

  - **"Index"** is a physical structure (usually a B-Tree) that changes performance characteristics of the database, but (unlike key) is not intended to change the meaning of data (but see unique index below).
  - Keys are not indexes and indexes are not keys, although they are often used together for performance reasons<sup>1</sup>.
  - An index underneath primary key is called **"primary index"**, remaining indexes are **"secondary"**.
  - An index can be unique or non-unique, with slight difference in the physical structure.
  - If a whole table is stored inside a B-Tree (as opposed to a combination of B-Tree(s) and table heap), such B-Tree is called **"clustered index"**. Under MS SQL Server, PRIMARY KEY defaults to clustered index, unless you specify NONCLUSTERED. MS SQL Server will also allow you to define clustered index different from primary key (unlike most other DBMSes). For more on clustering see [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).
  - **Foreign key** is not a key, it just references key.

Unique index is an oddball here, and should be viewed as a special case. If tends to be slightly narrower than non-unique index, and is *typically* used to enforce a key. However it can also be used without a key, in which case it may behave more-or-less similar as if it had a key. How similar, depends on DBMS<sup>2</sup>.

So to answer your question: under MS SQL Server, unique index with or without UNIQUE constraint are quite similar in practice, but you should still view them as separate concepts. I'd use UNIQUE constraint (with unique index underneath it) as a default, to make it more self-documenting and consistent with how other DBMSes work.

---

*<sup>1</sup> DBMSes often force, or at least default to an index underneath every key. But this is not always the case - for example Oracle will allow keys without indexes, or keys with non-unique indexes (it will even require non-unique indexes for deferred keys).*

*<sup>2</sup> Under MS SQL Server, its quite similar. Under Oracle, for example, you can't reference a unique index from FOREIGN KEY, you must reference a proper key.*

Comment: thanks for the reply, i dealt with Oracle & Sql server DB. so practically speaking in SQL server having an unique Key is similar to defining an Index and setting its unique property to true ?? is that right ?

Comment: @johnG Yup. MS SQL Server is more "forgiving" about that than other DBMSes.